c7n-mailer is listing out all the resources, how do only notify issues?
Using
- name: c7n-mailer-test
  resource: sqs
  filters:
    - "tag:MailerTest": absent
  actions:
    - type: notify
#      template: default
#      priority_header: '2'
#      subject: testing the c7n mailer
#        slack_template: slack_default
      slack_msg_color: danger
      to:
        - albert@onehouse.ai
        - slack://albert@onehouse.ai
      transport:
        type: sqs
        queue: https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/654654235321/cloudcustodian

and it's messaging me all the sqs resources.
Custodian
Resources
QueueURL: https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/654654235321/cloudcustodian QueueArn: arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:654654235321:cloudcustodian
QueueURL: https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/654654235321/onehouse-oh-project-sunnyvalelabs-load_hoodie_s3_sqs QueueArn: arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:654654235321:onehouse-oh-project-sunnyvalelabs-load_hoodie_s3_sqs
QueueURL: https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/654654235321/onehouse-oh-project-sunnyvalelabs-load_hoodie_s3_sqs_dlq QueueArn: arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:654654235321:onehouse-oh-project-sunnyvalelabs-load_hoodie_s3_sqs_dlq
Account
Region
us-west-2
Violation Description
Action Description


Change the resource: sqs to resource:ec2.
